# DirectX 11: Z-Fighting

Tags: c++, 3d, directx-11, hlsl

I am getting a strange rendering issue. [image: Rendering error example][image: Head]

Here's a video example http://youtu.be/PI7QUDN6AHI

AFAIK I am correctly sending the positions, normals, uv texture coordinates to my shader:

```
VertexShaderOutput VS(VertexShaderInput pInput)
{
    VertexShaderOutput lOutput;
    lOutput.position = mul(pInput.position, WorldViewProjectionMatrix);
    lOutput.uv = pInput.uv;
    lOutput.normal = mul(pInput.normal, WorldViewProjectionMatrix);
    return lOutput;
}

PixelShaderOutput PS(VertexShaderOutput pInput)
{
    PixelShaderOutput lOutput;
    lOutput.color = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, pInput.uv);
    return lOutput;
}
```

I have tested different models and this issue seems to arise when there is geometry behind the front facing triangles. I also don't get this problem when I simply return a color back from the pixel shader. The winding and the culling seems to be correct:

```
FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
CullMode = D3D11_CULL_FRONT;
FrontCounterClockwise = false;
```

I am not sure if this has something to do with the depth buffer?
What is likely to cause this problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: It looks like the "holes" don't line up with the triangles I'd expect the geometry to be drawn from, which points to some kind of clipping with other data. Perhaps not clearing the depth buffer or somehow getting stale depth data. Does it flicker? Maybe an issue with the projection matrix.

Comment: It doesn't flicker. I think the problem may be z fighting. I clear the buffer using: ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0, 1);

Comment: @DanielSamson just for future reference, the shading language of Direct3D is called HLSL. GLSL is the shading language of OpenGL

Comment: Oh yeah simple typo the h and g key are so close together. :D

Comment: @DanielSamson you should adjust the tag too

Comment: @jozxyqk http://youtu.be/PI7QUDN6AHI

Comment: Maybe an obvious solution - ones we all overlook initially - Have you actually enabled depth buffering?